# Will the attempt to read an improper value into a variable change its value?

Tags: input, error-handling, fortran, fortran2003

If the `iostat` keyword is present, a program does not stop if an I/O error occurs. Then, if I try to read an improper value into a scalar variable, `i` say, will this variable remain unchanged? The following seems to work:

```
program test
   integer :: i, stat

   i = 1

   do
      write (*, "('i = ')", advance='no')
      read (*, *, iostat=stat) i

      if (stat .eq. 0) then
         write (*, "('Valid integer. i has been set to ', I0)") i
      else
         write (*, "('Bad integer. i is still ', I0)") i
      end if
   end do
end program test
```

Can I rely on this behavior in Fortran 2003?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the value of the variable after an unsuccessful read is undefined.

Fortran 2008, 9.11.2

> If an error condition occurs during
>   execution of an input/output statement that contains either an ERR=
>   specifier or an IOSTAT= specifier then:
>
> ...
>
> if the statement is a READ statement or the error condition occurs in
>   a wait operation for a transfer initiated by a READ statement, all
>   input items or namelist group objects in the statement that initiated
>   the transfer become undefined;

Comment: Is it just because of the behavior of a certain compiler (in my case gfortran) that the above code works and not because of the standard (I couldn't find anything there)?

Comment: Yes, but it may well fail in another circumstances even with the same compiler. Read the whole section 9.11 in the F2008 standard.

Comment: Now I also found this in Fortran 2003, 9.10.1. Thanks!